# Lumen + Angular Upload Issue

Tags: javascript, angular, api, lumen

I'm trying to create image upload but i'm running into an issue when I try and upload a file through the Angular app it doesn’t upload but when I try and upload an image through Postman it uploads file.

I believe it has something to do with the Content-Type as when I've been trying to find out the issue and disable Content-Type in Postman i stop getting the same error and it works fine.

Here is the request headers from my Angular app that doesn’t work when uploading an image.

{status: "error", error: "File not found"}

[image: Here is the request headers from my Angular app]

When I disable Content-Type in the header it uploads fines but if I was to enable it I would get the same error as above.
[image: Postman]

```
public upload(file: File)
    {
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', file);

        let url = ':api:/assets';

        let observable = Observable.create(
            (observer) => {
                this
                    .baseApiService
                    .getHttpClient()
                    .post(
                        url,
                        data,
                        {
                            observe: 'response',
                        }
                    )
                    .subscribe(
                        (response) => {
                            let data  = response.body;
                            let asset = AssetModel.fromData(data);
                            observer.next(asset);
                            observer.complete();
                        },
                        (error) => {
                            observer.error(error);
                            observer.complete();
                        }
                    );
            }
        );

        return observable;
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your source code that's uploading the file in Angular?

Comment: @AshutoshKS I've added the code

Comment: I've added the change in the answer. Could you give it a try?

Comment: I see that Postman just has 1 header, but the request from Angular has many headers. I guess one of them is causing the issue: have you tested them all? Also, maybe you can switch to some other client or use the browser's default?

Answer (score 0):

As per your testing, if it's the issue with headers, then you can edit headers in your request. I hope you're using the Angular's HttpClient. If yes, please modify your code as given below:

```js
/* I'm trying to unset the header since we can't directly remove it */

.post(
    url,
    data,
    {
        observe: 'response',
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': '' /* OR set to 'image/jpeg' or 'image/png' */
        })
    }
)
```

**Read more** about HttpClient's headers: https://angular.io/guide/http#http-headers

Comment: I have just given that are try and the same thing is still happening

Comment: @Rickstar Did you check this request in network tools? What Content-Type was there?

Comment: Content-Type is not coming up in the Request Header

Comment: i'm getting the following in the payload

Comment: ------WebKitFormBoundaryRjNA2tsij5eqrBjA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="P1050938.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryRjNA2tsij5eqrBjA--